# Platinum God not unlocking

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I realize that this question might have been asked already, but I searched several sites and wikis, but I could not find out.

**Why is the Platinum God not unlocking for me?**

I did everything, except the unlocks for the Lost. I have got all other achivements and I also picked up all items, except some Lost items (I got some Lost items, because of a D4).

Pictures showing my progress:
(I can only post two links, the first two item pages are complete)

[image: Items 3]
[image: Items 4]

I got all challenges, have done everything with all characters (except the Lost) on normal and beat Moms Heart on Hard. I unlocked all endings and also beat Mega Satan and I'm playing on PC.

This should cover everything and I still didn't unlock Platinum God (not the real Platinum God, I'm not that crazy yet!) and I'm kind of out of options. Does anyone have a solution? (I restarted the game several times, did more runs, beat Mega Satan again, but still nothing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item you are missing in the sixth row of the first page you showed is [Missing No.](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Missing_No.), which is unlocked by beating Boss Rush with Lazarus.

The wiki has a [Collection Page](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Collection_Page) page, which shows what item would go in each slot of the collection page.

Comment: Huh, for some reason I was very sure, that this is a Lost item. Silly me! Seems like this item will be quite hard to get. Anyway, thanks for the hint!

Comment: Ha! One run later, I actually found it and got my Platinum God! :)